# How to translate millis to date and group by month and year in Jooq?

Tags: java, sql, orm, dsl, jooq

I have the following SQL which works as expected:

```
select  YEAR(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(creation_date / 1000), @@session.time_zone, "Europe/Berlin")) as year,
    MONTH(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(creation_date / 1000), @@session.time_zone, "Europe/Berlin")) as month,
    sum(value)
from transaction
GROUP BY year, month;
```

I'm trying to recreate these SQL in Jooq, but I don't know how to create a Date object from the milliseconds I have as `creation_date` in my database.

```
dsl.select(DSL.month(DSL.date(TRANSACTION.CREATION_DATE)), // This does not work
           DSL.year(DSL.date(TRANSACTION.CREATION_DATE)), // This does not work
           DSL.sum(TRANSACTION.VALUE))
       .from(TRANSACTION)
       .groupBy(???); // How to group by month and year?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common confusion when writing SQL `GROUP BY` is [the logical order of SQL operations](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/). While syntactically, `SELECT` seems to appear before `GROUP BY`, logically the order is inverse. This means that you cannot really reference columns in the `SELECT` clause from the `GROUP BY` clause.

Some dialects may have implemented exceptions "for convenience", but this is generally very confusing. I recommend not doing that.

But to solve your problem:

#### Producing the SQL you wanted to produce

While in your original SQL query, you used aliases for your two expressions (`AS year` and `AS month`), in the jOOQ query you did not. I recommend you use aliases as well, and assign the column expressions to local variables for reuse in the `groupBy()` clause:

```java
Field<?> month = DSL.month(DSL.date(TRANSACTION.CREATION_DATE)).as("month");
Field<?> year  = DSL.year(DSL.date(TRANSACTION.CREATION_DATE)).as("year");

dsl.select(month, year, DSL.sum(TRANSACTION.VALUE))
   .from(TRANSACTION)
   .groupBy(month, year)
   .fetch();
```

Aliased columns produce the full declaration in the `SELECT` clause, but only the alias in all other clauses, so this does exactly what you wanted:

```sql
SELECT
  month(date(transaction.creation_date)) as month,
  year(date(transaction.creation_date)) as year
  sum(transaction.value)
FROM transaction
GROUP BY
  month,
  year;
```

#### A better SQL statement according to the logical order of operations

If you want your SQL to remain portable and correct according to the logical order of SQL operations I've mentioned, I recommend you write this instead:

```java
Field<?> month = DSL.month(DSL.date(TRANSACTION.CREATION_DATE));
Field<?> year  = DSL.year(DSL.date(TRANSACTION.CREATION_DATE));

dsl.select(month.as("month"), year.as("year"), DSL.sum(TRANSACTION.VALUE))
   .from(TRANSACTION)
   .groupBy(month, year)
   .fetch();
```

Notice that I've moved the aliasing to the `SELECT` clause, whereas in the `GROUP BY` clause, I'm now referencing the full column expressions. This will produce thef ollowing query:

```sql
SELECT
  month(date(transaction.creation_date)) as month,
  year(date(transaction.creation_date)) as year
  sum(transaction.value)
FROM transaction
GROUP BY
  month(date(transaction.creation_date)),
  year(date(transaction.creation_date));
```

The full expressions are now expanded into the `GROUP BY` clause, without you having to repeat them manually.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, @Lukas Eder At the moment I am blocked by the problem on how to create a date from TRANSACTION.CREATION_DATE as the datatype in the database is long, it is a unix timestamp.

Comment: @AnnaIraHurnaus: I'll be happy to answer a new, separate question about that

Comment: Here is the separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848890/how-to-select-unix-timestamp-as-date-in-jooq