# Spring boot convert epoch timestamp to java.time.LocalDate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, java-time, localdate

I want to compare LocalDate with the timestamp in database (Postgres with UTC timezone).

code I wrote

```
@Query("""
      select eve from Events eve
      where cast(to_timestamp(pe.timestamp) as LocalDate)  = :curDate
   """)
  List<Event> getAllByDate(LocalDate curDate);
```

I added both

```
  @PostConstruct
  public void init(){
    // Setting Spring Boot SetTimeZone
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
  }
```

and

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

then I tried to run

select to_timestamp(eve.timestamp)

inside @Query where eve.timestamp was 1664584019 and it converted into 2022-10-01 18:39:59.0

First I through it is converting into IST (Indian standard time) but I think that also wrong.

So, Can anybody help me regarding how to convert epoch time to LocalDate to compare with LocalDate?

Comment: 1664584019 equals GMT: Saturday 1. October 2022 00:26:59. So it seems you got the correct date in this case, but where the time 18:39:59.0 comes from is a mystery to me.

Comment: In Java it’s easy enough: `Instant.ofEpochSecond(1664584019).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate()`. How much of that works in a JOQL query I don’t know. If all else fails, you may convert the first and the last timestamp of the current date to epoch timestamps and select events between them.

Comment: Lesson to learn: Do not store numeric timestamps in your database. Use `timestamp with time zone` data type.

Comment: Is there sill a way that somehow I will be able to use some SQL function which just convert the epoch to UTC time. I tried everything. And I know at the end if there were now choice, I have to use startTimestamp and endtimestamp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select unix timestamp as date in Jooq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848890/how-to-select-unix-timestamp-as-date-in-jooq) Does this? [PostgreSQL: how to convert from Unix epoch to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609722/postgresql-how-to-convert-from-unix-epoch-to-date) Also see [How to Convert a Unix Timestamp to a Date/Time Value in PostgreSQL](https://database.guide/how-to-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-date-time-value-in-postgresql/).

Answer (score 1):

> Can anybody help me regarding how to convert epoch time to LocalDate?

You can convert the epoch seconds into an `Instant` which can subsequently be converted into an `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` depending on your time-zone requirement. Finally, you can get the `LocalDate` out of the `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` using its `.toLocalDate()` function.

**Note**: The following demo uses `ZoneOffset.UTC`. You can use a different offset e.g. `ZoneOffset.of("+05:30")` to get an `OffsetDateTime` at this offset or a `ZoneId` e.g. `ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")` to get a `ZonedDateTime` at this time-zone.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long epochSeconds = 1664584019;
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSeconds);
        System.out.println(instant);

        // Get LocalDate out of Instant
        LocalDate date = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-10-01T00:26:59Z
2022-10-01
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/fmlRXv)

**Note**: Since you want to compare a `LocalDate` at UTC with `curDate`, the value of `curDate` should also be obtained at UTC i.e. `curDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)`.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: But I need to do it in JPQL, it's creating weird timezone issues